# Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL cluster0.b4oyxi0.mongodb.net

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a MERN stack application. My Node web server used to work fine. Recently however, whenever I start my Node server, I get the following error:

```
[1] Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL cluster0.b4oyxi0.mongodb.net
[0] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api/users/login to http://localhost:5000/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[1] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the error means. I encountered a similar error and the non +srv connection string did it for me.

To get one,

1. head out to your Atlas Dashboard under Database Deployment,
2. click **Connect**,
3. then choose **Connect your application**.
4. On the Node.js driver version, lower that to **2.2.12 or later**.
   This should give the connection string.

Comment: is there no other solution than downgrading?

Answer (score 0):

It's a DNS server issue. Try changing your DNS server in your network settings to any of these, or any other trusted one you know:

1. 208.67.222.222
2. 1.1.1.1
3. 8.8.8.8
4. 9.9.9.9

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my MongoDB connection and was able to resolve it by adding `0.0.0.0` to the host of my TypeORM configuration. This is because `0.0.0.0` is a wildcard IP address that allows connections from any IP address, whereas the default value of `localhost` only allows connections from the same machine.

If you’re facing a similar issue, try adding `0.0.0.0` to your configuration file as well and see if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure what the error means. I have identified the error and resolved it using these methods. It's a simple error that can be fixed by making a small change in the code. Just like the screenshot below, take a look at the code and I am sure your error will be resolved.

[click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2JFk.png)

The code is written using the wrong method "next()" middlewear define the space as shown in the screenshot below.

[click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95aAW.png)

sometime it also happens

[click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Ljy.png)

The asynchronous space doesn't define where the error is being rendered. Some spaces resolve this issue.

[click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJsmH.png)